# How to loop through all Math methods in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

I want to loop through all methods in `Math` object in JavaScript.

I have tried:

```js
for(const [name ,function] of Object.entries( Math )) { /* code */ }
```

but `Object.entries` returns an empty array every time for some reason.

Is there a way to loop through all of the `Math` functions?

Comment: The "for some reason" is that `Object.entries`, like `Object.keys`, only provides *enumerable* properties, but the methods on `Math` aren't enumerable.

Comment: Also, `function` is a keyword. You can't use keywords as variable names.